# What is the best test to compare two sets of continuous data to see if they differ at each pair and overall?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, continuous-data

I have two sets of data comparing the mean consumption of 4 materials before and after a new production standard have been introduced. i have 4 different materials and the consumption of each one is independent than the other. I would like to see if the new standard have led to decrease in consumption of each material and a decrease in General amount as well. I'm thinking of using Mann Whitney U Test. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not if you have _paired_ data. Further description of the situation and data would help. What 'randomly chosen' experimental units are being tested? Does each unit have a Before and After score for each of the four 'materials'?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have four materials, the measurement will be in mean consumption per day(Kg/d) with paired measurements before the new standard and after it. I need to find if the consumption of each material have decreased. and also if in general my new standard have led to decrease consumption of all materials together.

Comment: Once again: what experimental units? Materials themselves, firms using these materials? Days when consumption takes place? // Take one of the four materials. What data do you have 'before'? How many numbers? What data after 'after'? In what way are data before comparable with data after? // Not necessarily asking for your data, but requre detailed plan by which data collected.